# Issue while looping an array in laravel view

Tags: arrays, loops, laravel

Hi i have 2 arrays returned from a controller.

**$order**

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'orderid' => int 1
      'ostatus' => string 'Placed' (length=6)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'orderid' => int 4
      'ostatus' => string 'Placed' (length=6)
```

**$orderdetails**

```
array (size=2)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => 
        array (size=3)
          'oid' => int 1
          'img6_path' => string 'images/product-list/pro1-list.jpg' (length=33)
          'brand_name' => string 'Puma' (length=4)
      1 => 
        array (size=3)
          'oid' => int 1
          'img6_path' => string 'images/product-list/pro2-list.jpg' (length=33)
          'brand_name' => string 'DressBerry' (length=10)    
      2 => 
        array (size=3)
          'oid' => int 1
          'img6_path' => string 'images/product-list/pro3-list.jpg' (length=33)
          'brand_name' => string 'United Colors of Benetton' (length=25)
  4 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          'oid' => int 4
          'img6_path' => string 'images/product-list/pro4-list.jpg' (length=33)
          'brand_name' => string 'Puma' (length=4)
```

I am trying to print it in this order:

[image]

This is what i have been doing:

```
foreach($order as $ord)
  //printing order id
foreach($orderdetail as $od)
foreach($od as $x)
  //printing the products
endforeach()
endforeach()
endforeach()
```

But this is printing

- orderid 1 with 3 products
- orderid 1 with 1 product (That belonged to orderid 4)
- orderid 4 with 3 products (That belonged to orderid 1)
- orderid 4 with 1 product

Can anyone tell me how should i loop through the array so that after printing the first 3 products in order1 the loop breaks out and then print the 1 product in order 4 (Like in the picture above). Thanks

Comment: create join query for controller

Answer (score 1):

```
@foreach($order as $ord)
  //printing order id
    @foreach($orderdetail[$ord->orderid] as $od)
        @foreach($od as $x)
            //printing the products
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

where `@foreach($orderdetail[$ord->orderid] as $od)` is the big change... I would give this a try...

Comment: @8yt3c0d3 In case this solved your issue, would you mind giving the answer the grean check? Kind of hunting for reputation here :-)